# How to set v-data-table row class with Vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetifyjs3

How to set `v-data-table` row class with Vuetify 3?

With Vuetify 2, I used to set `:rowClass="myfuntion()"`.

Answer (score 1):

Now in Vuetify 3 you can use **:row-props** for that:

```
<v-data-table
  :row-props="rowProps"
>

</v-data-table>
...
methods: {
    rowProps(data) {
        return {
            class: {
                'your-class': true,
                'is-selectable': data.item.isSelectable,
            },
        };
    }
}
```

This way you should be able to assign not only class, but any VDataTableRow prop

Answer (score 0):

In vue 3, You can use the **row-class** property instead of :**rowClass**.

Comment: is it documented somewhere?

Comment: `:rowClass` has been removed